# Array comparison test

Tags: arrays, 2d

This has been giving meet a lot of trouble. I don't understand why the test is failing. arrayToString is supposed to take the values of array1 and store it so that it compared to correctAnswer.

```
public static String arrayToString(int[][] a) {
    String string = "";
    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < a[0].length; col++) {
            string += a[row][col] + " ";
        }
        string += "\n";
    }
    return string;
}
```

The main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    private static int[][] array1 = { 
        {3, 2, 1, 1},
        {2, 5, 6, 2},
        {1, 2, 9, 8}
    };

    String methodCallResult, correctAnswer;
        System.out.println("Testing arrayToString method:");
        methodCallResult = FindTheSums.arrayToString(array1);
        correctAnswer = "3 2 1 1\n2 5 6 2\n1 2 9 8";
        if(methodCallResult.equals(correctAnswer)){
            System.out.println("arrayToString(array1) test passed");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("arrayToString(array1) test failed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test is failing because you have a space after each letter. Here you dont.

```
correctAnswer = "3 2 1 1\n2 5 6 2\n1 2 9 8";

                       ^^        ^^

string += a[row][col] + " ";

                  space ^^
```

This would match

```
correctAnswer = "3 2 1 1 \n2 5 6 2 \n1 2 9 8 ";

                  space ^^   space^^   space^^
```

**Edit:** possible solution with method change

```
public static String arrayToString(int[][] a) {
    String string = "";
    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < a[0].length; col++) {
            if (col == a[0].length - 1) {  // add the if statement to check for
                string += a[row][col];     // end of row. End of row adds no space.
            } else {
                string += a[row][col] + " ";
            }
        }
        string += "\n";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Yes, look at the bottom of my answer

Comment: correctAnswer is set. I can only change my method. what if I did    `code`for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
    string += a[row][col];
    if (col == a[row].length - 1) {
     string += "\n";
    } else
     string += " ";
   }

Comment: See my edit. I added a condition to check for the end of the row. In that case, you wouldn't add a space. You add a space to all others.

Comment: Yes, your solution looks just like mine. You may be a little off, but your thinking in the right direction. The statement should be `if /else` not just `if`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a space at the end of the conversion.

```
for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < a[0].length; col++) {
        string += a[row][col] + " ";
                                ^^^
    }
    string += "\n";
}
```

Therefore, `correctAnswear` should be `3 2 1 1 \n2 5 6 2 \n1 2 9 8;`.

Comment: do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @user3002801 If you could modify `correctAnswear` it would work, if not, do as peeskillet says.